# Mutual Uniqueness of Operations in PA models

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let us consider the first-order theory of Peano arithmetic (from now on PA) formulated in the vocabulary with just $+$ (for addition) and $\cdot$ (for multiplication). This vocabulary restriction is not important at all since $0$, succesor $S$, and the order $\leq$ can be defined using first-order formulas.

I am curious what it is known about the dependency, in non standard models, of each one of these basic operations with respect to the other. To be more precise, I am interested on any known answer to the following two questions:

1. Are there two different (i.e., non-isomorphic) PA models with the same universe and the same interpretation of multiplication?
2. Are there two different (i.e., non-isomorphic) PA models with the same universe and the same interpretation of addition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following closely related results may interest you.

$1.$ The isomorphism type of the multiplicative semigroup of a model of PA determines, up to isomorphism, the additive semigroup of the model. This is not surprising, since one can define a relation $R(y,x)$ that behaves like $y=2^x$.

$2.$ For *countable* models of PA, the isomorphism type of the additive semigroup determines the isomorphism type of the multiplicative semigroup.

The above two quite old results are due to Ehrenfeucht.

$3.$ For *uncountable* models of PA, the isomorphism type of the additive semigrop does not determine the isomorphism type of the multiplicative semigroup.

Information can be found in [this paper by Kossak, Nadel, and Schmerl,](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2274754?uid=3739400&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3737720&uid=4&sid=21100793540951) which unfortunately does not seem to be freely available.

Comment: Great. This paper is exactly what I was looking for.